# How do I convert if else to && || in if the result is the same

Tags: java, algorithm, if-statement, logic, pseudocode

how do i replace if else to && || if the output for each condition is the same in these cases

there are multiple different conditions to be met before reaching the outputs and each case has the same output.

Note that the conditions and outputs are just placeholders since this is mostly a pseudo code question

Case 1:

```
if(condition 1){
    if(condition 2){
        if(condition 3){
            if(condition 4){
                if(condition 5){
                    return(1);
                }
                if(condition 6){
                    if(condition 7){
                        return(1);
                    } 
                }
            }else{
                if(condition 10){
                     return(1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Case 2:

```
if(condition 1){
    if(condition 2){
        if(condition 3){
            if(condition 4){
                if(condition 6){
                    if(condition 8){
                         return(2);
                        }   
                }else{
                    if(condition 9){
                        return(2);
                    }
                }
            }
        }else{
            if(condition 11){
                  return(2);
            }
        }
    }else{
        if(condition 12){
            return(2);
        }
    }
}else if(condition 13){
    if(condition 14){
        return(2);
    }
}
```

can it be possible to reduce both the cases to 1 if statement each by using && and || operators with the conditions since both return a single result despite having multiple conditions

the solution I am looking for would look something like:
Case 1:

```
if((condition1 && condition 2) || (condition 3)){
   return (1);
}
```

Case 2:

```
if((condition1 && condition 2) || (condition 4)){
   return (2);
}
```

Comment: What code have you tried?  What result did you observe?

Comment: I just need help with the logic of it since thats what confused me

Comment: @ulti What do you mean 'something like'? There are no 'OR's implicit in the code in your question.

Comment: You can use `if(condition_1 && condition_2 && condition_3 && (condition_4? condition_5 || condition_6 && condition_7: condition_10)) return 1;`, however, if you can’t come up with this solution yourself, chances are high that you will have difficulties reading and understanding this code when you come back at a later time where the longer form has been forgotten. So you’re better off keeping the verbose form you can read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in case all the conditions have the same result, then you can condition it like this:

case1:

```
if ( (condition1 && condition2 && condition3) && ((condition4 && condition5) || (condition4 && condition6 && condition7) || (condition10)) ) return(1);
```

case2:

```
if ( (condition1 && ((condition2 && ((condition3 && condition4 && ((condition6 && condition8) || condition9)) || condition11)) || condition12)) || (condition13 && condition14)) return(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you thinking about something like this?

```
if(condition 1 && condition 2 && condition 3 && condition 4){
if(condition 5){ return 1}
if(condition 6 && condition 7){ return 1}
...
}
```

It would definitely help to clarify a bit more though!

Comment: something like 
if ((condition 1 && condition 2)|| condition 3){
  return(1);
}
since its the same result its possible to have it all in a single if statement per case right?

Comment: I tried editing my question to make it more clear

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).